# How to constrain two columns in SQL to have a value in one column only be allowed to appear in combination with the value in the other column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have two columns in a table:
- For one row all two columns need to be filled.
- In col1 any ID is allowed.
- In col2 a specific ID once set is only allowed to appear for further rows in combination with the ID in col1 when it was set for the first time.

Example:

```
 col1 | col2
------|------
   1  |  1        OK
   1  |  1        OK
   1  |  2        OK
   2  |  3        OK
   2  |  1        NOK because 1 in col2 is already associated with 1 in col1.
   1  |  3        NOK because 3 in col2 is already associated with 2 in col1.
```

I want to apply this rule to a table using a constraint. (Without having to use a second table)

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

As you want to allow only one col1 value per col2 value you need a col2 table:

```
create table tcol2
(
  col2 int,
  col1 int,
  primary key (col2)
);
```

Then you could just add a count column to this table (so you'd have col1, col2, and counter instead of multiple rows per col1 and col2) or you use your existing table with a constraint:

```
alter table mytable add constraint
  fk_mytable_tcol2 foreign key (col1, col2) references tcol2 (col1, col2);
```

Comment: That is the proper solution: normalize the data model.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I made a mistake in my data model, so I wanted to know if there is a solution using only constraints and no second table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an EXCLUDE constraint to do this.  you would want to exclude cases where col2 are = but col1 is <>.

```
create extension btree_gist;

create table foobar (col1 int not null, col2 int not null);

alter table foobar add constraint foobar_ex exclude using gist
   (col2 with =, col1 with <>);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fix your data model.  You should have a table with one row per `col2` value and an associated `col1` value:

```
create table col2_col1_lookup as (
     col2 int primary key,
     col1 int unique
);
```

You can lookup the `col1` value in this table.